# Convert a letter to its corresponding control code

Tags: ruby, control-characters

Given a single letter (string), say `"a"`, I want to convert this into its corresponding control code, i.e. `"\ca"` - or equivalently (in alternate syntax) - `"\C-a"`, `?\ca`, `"\x01"`, `"\u0001"`

I was hoping there'd be some "nice", clean way of doing this conversion, but I can't figure it out.

An obvious first attempt might be to try something like:

```
def convert_to_control_code(letter)
  "\c#{letter}"
end
```

...But this does not work, since this will always return `"\u0003{letter}"` (where `"\u0003"` is the control code `"\c#"`

My current solution is simply to "brute force" it by doing the following:

```
def convert_to_control_code(letter)
  (0..255).detect { |x| x.chr =~ Regexp.new("\\c#{char}") }.chr
end
```

However, I can't help but feel there's a "right" way of doing this!

**Edit:**

Here's another, non brute-force solution I've come up with, that seems to work:

```
def convert_to_control_code(letter)
  (letter.ord % 32).chr
end
```

This looks much nicer, but also very hacky!

Answer (score 1):

You can write it as :

```
def convert_to_control_code(letter)
  eval "?\\C-#{letter.chr}" 
end

convert_to_control_code(97) # => "\u0001"
convert_to_control_code(98) # => "\u0002"
```

Comment: Hmmm... I'm getting some funny results with other inputs, for example: `convert_to_control_code("?") # => "\u007F"` but `"\u007F".match(/\c?/) # => nil`

Comment: ...Whereas my "hacky" solutions returned: `convert_to_control_code("?") # => "\x1F"` and `"\x1F".match(/\c?/) # => #<MatchData "\x1F">`

Comment: @TomLord: Your ”hacky” solution is wrong: ["\c?".ord == 0o177](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_0/parse.y#L6001-L6002).

Comment: It seems you're correct. However (!!) why does the `.match` above return false? As it happens, although I didn't think it important to mention this in the original question, this is the context that I need it to work in!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to do the same as [Ruby itself does](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/632fb2e15b91949211b85475d35a9653bdbf5702/parse.y#L6021-L6024). It might look something like this:

```
def convert_to_control(letter)
  letter = letter.chr # ensure we are only dealing with a single char
  return 0177.chr if letter == '?'
  raise 'an error' unless letter.ascii_only? # or do something else
  (letter.ord & 0x9f).chr
end
```

You might want to change the encoding of the result depending on what you are doing.

Comment: This is actually very similar to the second method in the question, in fact I don’t really know why the value is ANDed with 0x9f instead of 31 (I think the 32 in the question is wrong).